# Eigenvector in the image or kernel of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If vector $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf A$, then vector $\mathbf v$ must be in the kernel of $\mathbf A$ or in the image of $\mathbf A$.

I'm pretty new to the topic of eigen-anything, but is this statement always true? It'd be in the image if, for example, the vector was parallel to the span of a line, and $\mathbf v$ is in the kernel if it were to be perpendicular to that line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\mathbf v$'s associated eigenvalue is $\lambda$.

If $\lambda=0$, then $\mathbf{Av}=\mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf v\in\operatorname{ker}\mathbf A$.

If $\lambda\ne0$, then $\mathbf A(\mathbf v/\lambda)=\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf v\in\operatorname{im}\mathbf A$.